# gwtbootstrap3. How to justified ButtonGroup element with buttons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, gwtbootstrap3

I would like to justified my button group to whole width of parent.

I am trying to  [Justified button groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#with-button-elements)

Here is my code:

```
ButtonGroup buttonGroupHelper = new ButtonGroup();

Button loginButton = new Button("Log in");
Button resetButton = new Button("Reset");
Button forgotCredentialsButton = new Button("Forgot credentials?");

buttonGroupHelper.add(loginButton);
buttonGroupHelper.add(resetButton);
buttonGroupHelper.add(forgotCredentialsButton);
```

And I am getting this:
[image]

When I will add this line:

```
buttonGroupHelper.setJustified(true);
```

I am getting this:
[image]

I use [bootstrap css darkly theme](https://bootswatch.com/darkly/).

Here is html that my gwtbootstrap3 framework produce:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-play-circle-o"></i> Log in</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i> Reset</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-key"></i> Forgot credentials?</button>
</div>
```

Am I doing something wrong. Or is this just a bug?

Please help.

Comment: Can you add the css as well? Also you should update your title to make it easier to read

Comment: Without adding the CSS, it is hard for us to find a solution.

Comment: I use oryginal bootstrap theme. Added info to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the buttons inside button groups and then put the button groups inside the helper button group.

```
ButtonGroup buttonGroupHelper = new ButtonGroup();
ButtonGroup loginBtnGroup = new ButtonGroup();
ButtonGroup resetBtnGroup = new ButtonGroup();
ButtonGroup forgotBtnGroup = new ButtonGroup();

Button loginButton = new Button("Log in");
Button resetButton = new Button("Reset");
Button forgotCredentialsButton = new Button("Forgot credentials?");

loginBtnGroup.add(loginButton);
resetBtnGroup.add(resetButton);
forgotBtnGroup.add(forgotCredentialsButton);

buttonGroupHelper.add(loginBtnGroup);
buttonGroupHelper.add(resetBtnGroup);
buttonGroupHelper.add(forgotBtnGroup);

buttonGroupHelper.setJustified(true);
```

Comment: I've had to miss that. Thanks for answer :D